Add 60+ Named Ranges to VBA Chart through FOR Loop
I have a range of dynamic named ranges labled with numbers at the end, ie Log_Normal_1.... LogNormal_24
I want to be able to insert these into a chart quickly- doing this manually for 60-100 ranges is not going to be efficient (all are using dynamic a1:index(range, counta()) so not an option to not use these)
I Return error: Subscript out of range > my chart is on Sheet8 so am unsure what this is causing
Sub Calc()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 24
AddChart i
Next i
End Sub
Sub AddChart(i As Integer)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart").Activate
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart").SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.Name = "Log_Normal" & i
.Values = ThisWorkbook.Names("Log_Normal" & i).RefersToRange
End With
End Sub




Please double check the defined names. Is it Log_Normal_<IndexNum> or Log_Normal<IndexNum>? eg. run the code in Immediate Window For Each n In ThisWorkbook.Names: Debug.Print n.Name: Next

Did this- Returns Log_Normal1 and so forth

Exactly which line is causing the error?  Probably worth using ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet8") and not just Worksheets("Sheet8")

added that- i am not seeing a specific line that appears as an error, just the generic "subscript out of range" error.

When the error pops up, is there a "Debug" button?  If Yes what happens when you click it?

im not seeing a debub, i just moved it from the sheet 8 module to a workbook module and it no longer returns an error, but nothing is added onto my chart

No series are added, or series are added but there's no points on the chart?  Have you tried stepping through and debugging your code using F8?

You're not setting .Values for the series.  What type of chart is it?

added .values, it is a line chart with 20 existing series and 1 x axis time series

updated code above

So you updated your code - what does it do or not do now you've updated?  We can't see...  Your post still says you're getting "index out of range"

sorry about that- i am not communicating well haha! it runs, but nothing appears on the chart, nor if i check all active series- none of the series populate

This works for me:
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim cht As Chart, nm As Name, i As Long
    
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
    
    'first clear the chart
    Do While cht.SeriesCollection.count > 0
        cht.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
    Loop
    
    'add 4 series
    For i = 1 To 4
        Set nm = ThisWorkbook.Names("Dynamic" & i)
        With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .XValues = nm.RefersToRange.EntireRow.Columns("A")
            .Values = nm.RefersToRange
            .Name = nm.Name
        End With
    Next i
    
End Sub

Names:

Worksheet "trace":


wow! thank you!! marking as resolved. and horrible question i am new to vba- do i need to run this sub everytime i open the workbook to keep the series on the chart? or can i simply add these and not need to run the sub  again?

Once the series are on the chart they should stay there.
